# Cannot connect remote-redux-devtools in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux

I cannot connect `remote-redux-devtools` debugger in chrome and getting this error:

```
SocketProtocolError {
  name: "SocketProtocolError", 
  message: "Socket hung up", 
  code: 1006, 
  stack: "SocketProtocolError: Socket hung up
         at SCSocke…e?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2648:44)"
}
```

my code is the following:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {persistReducer, persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import * as actions from './actions';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import {REMEMBER_LIST} from '../constants';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: REMEMBER_LIST,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({realtime: true});

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, it's need to use `remotedev-server`. As in document it's not recommend to use `remotedev-sever` golbally, but I get an error with using as dev dependency so I use globally. the instruction is:

1. install the `remotedev-server` globally
2. run `remotedev --port=8000`
3. open browser and go to `localhost:8000/socketcluster/` ( it's still getting error if it's not include `/socketcluster/` alias.
4. you have to add specific port number and computer's IP as following:

```
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  realtime: true,
  port: 8000,
  hostname: '192.168.1.106', //add your computer's IP
});
```

### UPDATE

the easier way is to use [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger), you don't need to do these headache steps